# What is this paper receipt found in the box for in WW84?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, wonder-woman-1984

Diana goes to find the dream stone back at the museum, she discovers the following piece of paper receipt which mentions the name of Max Lord and mentions "PAID".

[image]

What is this paper receipt for?

Comment: Receipt from a furniture delivery/installation business?  And it was underneath the excelsior in the Dream Stone's crate...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the start of the movie, the jewelry store is a front for black market items.  This is one of the items in the store room ( the camera zooms in on it when the criminals enter).  Max had purchased the stone and had not yet picked it up from the store. After the robbery, all of the items were impounded and Max had to track it down from the FBI to the Smithsonian.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up! I was totally confused on how this ended up in the box.